# Can self publishing be taken as a full time work?

Tags: self-publishing

Everyone is talking about self-publishing as a passive income source, not active.

Can self-publishing be taken as a full time work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make a full-time living self-publishing -- my partner does it.

That said, if you write novels and publish them yourself, you'll spend some money before you make any (you'll need to pay at least one editor, likely pay someone to create a cover, possibly pay someone to format the book to work correctly in epub, etc.).  Then you'll need to build a back list, because even if you write a best seller and get enough in a couple months to buy a house, it's the back list that pays the bills from month to month.

Based on my partner's experience, it generally takes about five years of writing top quality novels to build a backlist that will sell enough to keep a roof over your head after a best seller -- and probably longer than that, if you don't have that best seller to get people searching for your name.

So, short version: yes, it's possible, but it isn't quick, easy, or reliable.